# How can we synch sqlite (local) databse with mysql (server) database in iOS?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have created one app for iPad. I want to run it in both offline and online mode. For local we have created SQLITE database and for server side we are using MySQL with PHP API's. 
On both we have same database schemas.

I want to synch these both databases as soon as connect to internet so that data will be same in both.
And when I access same login form other device, data will be same as previous device.

What could be the way to deal with it ???